# Determine when a SpriteNode is leaving the screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I want to remove all objects out of the screen. For the moment I use a contact detection with "barriers".

I initialize barriers around the screen and when a SpriteNode is in contact with one of them it is removed from the scene. But this method doesn't work very well and crash my game.

Do you know if there is a simple method to remove all objects out of the screen?

Here my code with barriers :

```
// declarations
var barrierLeft:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var barrierRight:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var barrierTop:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

// In didMoveToView method
barrierLeft.size = CGSizeMake(1, self.frame.height*2)
barrierLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: barrierLeft.size)
barrierRight.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)

barrierLeft.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
barrierLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = barrierCategory
barrierLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = flechetteCategory
addChild(barrierLeft)

barrierRight.size = CGSizeMake(1, self.frame.height*2)
barrierRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: barrierLeft.size)
barrierRight.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width+10, 0)
barrierRight.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
barrierRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = barrierCategory
barrierRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = flechetteCategory
addChild(barrierRight)

//     
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!)
{
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody


    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB

    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & flechetteCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & barrierCategory) != 0)
    {
        flecheDidCollideWithbarrier(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, barrier: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
    }

//

func flecheDidCollideWithbarrier (fleche: SKSpriteNode, barrier: SKSpriteNode)
{
    println("barrière")
    counterGainTime = 0
    fleche.removeFromParent()


}
```

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the position of each node to determine if it is in the scene. You can then remove the nodes, accordingly.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    // Loop over all nodes in the scene
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") {
        node, stop in
        if (node is SKSpriteNode) {
            let sprite = node as SKSpriteNode
            // Check if the node is not in the scene
            if (sprite.position.x < -sprite.size.width/2.0 || sprite.position.x > self.size.width+sprite.size.width/2.0
                || sprite.position.y < -sprite.size.height/2.0 || sprite.position.y > self.size.height+sprite.size.height/2.0) {
                    sprite.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with your solution.

Comment: I have a problem. My function update is already used for an interval function. When I add your method in func update the node is not remove AND when each node is leavin the screen it add +1 to my score. My score is calculate on each contact between two bodies. I can't understand the relation between your method and my score. Moreover I edit your method outside the func update like this : if (node.position.x < 0 ||  node.position.x > self . size.width) || node.position.y < 0 || node.position.y > self.size.height) {node.removeFromParent()} the method works but not all time. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have an edge loop around the scene?

Comment: Sorry I just start the swift programmation and I don't know exactly what is an edge loop. I have loop during the game. My timer for example. My game consist to add in random interval physics bodies from the top of the screen and I have to destroy them from the bottom (like a space invaders)  with  60s to play.

Comment: Did you remove the barrier from your code? My code is meant to replace the code in your question.

Comment: Did you set the name property for each sprite?

Comment: Well, I'm home and it is more easy than from my iPhone. I test again your code exactly like you posted and I have an error : "SKNode does not have a member named size".

What did you mean with your last question ? 
I just want remove one sprite (the weapons) called "fleche" my code is :

Comment: self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("fleche") {
            node, stop in
            // Check if the node is not in the scene
            if (node.position.x < -node.size.width/2.0 || node.position.x > self.size.width+node.size.width/2.0
                || node.position.y < -node.size.height/2.0 || node.position.y > self.size.height+node.size.height/2.0) {
                    node.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

Did I forget something ?

Comment: I don't have the error anymore but nothing displaying in my debug area (I add println("outside")). Do I have to init something else to my SKSpriteNode called "fleche"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62467/discussion-between-0x141e-and-haox).